# Programmatically set the Typeface and set text style in xml not working

Tags: android, textview

I have a textview defined in xml, now i am setting the Typeface programmatically like this:

```
textView.setTypeface(APP_FONT_REGULAR); // which is custom font in assests (.ttf file).
```

now i have set `android:textStyle="bold"` in xml

but it's not applying bold?

what is the reason i need to apply my own Typface and set it to bold also.

Comment: show your xml file first where you apply this whole, is it a string resource by which you are doing this?

Comment: @pKs its just a simple textview with id, width, height and textstyle properties

Comment: I mean to say where does the text in the textview come from? And what type of text it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i need to apply my own Typface and set it to bold also.

You can set appearance when you call `setTypeface()` like this

```
textView.setTypeface(APP_FONT_REGULAR, Typeface.BOLD);
```

it solve your problem. Check it out.